# Not able to upload file of 1GB from filesystem, (hardcoded file not using input type file) using xhr from Electron application using node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, upload, electron

I need to upload a file reading from filesystem (not specified by the user) using xhr. Is there a way to send it via Ajax?

I understand that javascript has input type file, which gives javascript file object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File.
I tried getting file descriptor using Node fs APIs (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) . But am unable to send it via xhr. Here is my code snippet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(method, url);    
req.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

 var progress = 0;
  req.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
          progress = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
      }
   }, false);

   req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      // add logic for each state
   };

   var fs = require('fs');
   if (filename) {
       // get the file descriptor and send it via xhr
       fs.open(filename, "r", function(error, fd) {
       // -- THIS IS THE PART NOT WORKING --
       req.send(fd);
     });
   } else {
         console.log('no filename');
   }
```

Comment: Where is this code running - in Node or in the browser? The two environments are completely different; Node APIs are not available in the browser.

Comment: Code is running in Electron app, which is chromium container and has Node runtime available.

Comment: You are only sending out the `file descriptor` the actual data must be read with `fs.read()`

Comment: Thanks, yes I realized it - it was an integer. I tried using fs.readFile(...). But then I get the error: "RangeError: File size is greater than possible Buffer…." since my file is over 1GB. I can not load the entire file in memory since its huge. Is there any other alternate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the way to read a file. This is how you do it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(filename, { encoding : 'utf8' }, function(err, data){
    //data holds the contents of the file.
    req.send(data);
});
```

Comment: I tried using fs.readFile(...) already, But then I get the error: "RangeError: File size is greater than possible Buffer…." since my file is over 1GB. I can not load the entire file in memory since its huge. Is there any other alternate?

Comment: Maybe `fs.read()` would be a better idea... but you are going to need to use Node `http.clientRequest`

Comment: Thanks! Will try fs.read(fd, buffer, ..., callback) - but then I will have to read small buffers - 1kb at a time and then call req.send(..) with small buffers. Don't know if that works with xhr?

Comment: I don't know if you can send chunks with XHR, that's why I suggested `http.clientRequest` instead.

Comment: Yes, XHR that did not work. Is there any way, in node.js where I can get File object for a particular file from file system?

Comment: I tried creating hidden input file elements with filepath as value, but not able to trigger event with actual value.... Any ideas?                           var id;  // some id 
   var inputSel = "<input type=\"file\" name=\"nm\" id=\"" + id +  "\" value=\"" + fileProvided + "\" placeholder=\"plc\"/>";
   
  $("#fileUploadPlaceHolder").append($(inputSel));

   var fileData;
   function readFile(evt) {
         fileData = evt.target.files[0];
         console.log("fileContent: “,fileData);
    }

    $('#' + id).on('change', readFile);
    $('#' + id).trigger('change');

Comment: Hi, I am trying to implement using http.clientRequest, Is there a way to track the progress of file upload using http.clientRequest?  The way it was done with xhr was req.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
          progress = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
      }
   }, false);

Comment: Thanks MinusFour, using http.clientRequest helped - it works well with fs.createReadStream. I am looking for an efficient way to progress upload of file in termes of percent!